# order deny,allow not working in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have rules working fine in .htaccess such as force https. But the following *deny,allow* just won't work.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Can the .conf overrule the htaccess?  What should I look out for?  Are there any modules that could be causing this? The .htaccess itself works, it's just the *deny,allow* section.

The reason for this order is so that I can develop the non-live site without anyone seeing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this my moving the bad bot block into the vhost file of each domain and now use the vhost file to limit access. A bit of a pain not being to be able to do it globally for the bots so if anyone else has a better answer would be welcome :)

Comment: can you share what changes you made in vhost file

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't a fix to the issue just a workaround.  I no longer have this server and not had the issue since so couldn't provide you with anything I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride) clauses in your conf files. They basically give authorization to .htaccess to override the values in the .conf files.

Comment: Something odd is going on.  I added an AllowOverride all to /var/www/vhosts in the httpd.conf and it did not work, and I eventually got it working when I added / to AllowOverride All.  But obviously I don't want to do that for security reasons.  So I changed / to Limit as a test and that did not work so I changed back to All and its still not working even though I just had that working - :S ODD.  I have reloaded restarted and stopped and started apache several times. Oh and I am deep refreshing on every attempt

Comment: You probably have several .conf files. Usually we've one for each virtual host. In each virtual host you can set the AllowOverride option.

Comment: So for example I should be able to set:

    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

And this should allow override despite the AllowOverride for / being set to None.  Right?

I have added this into both the main httpd.conf and the vhosts file with no joy.  I have read through vhosts file and cannot see anything conflicting.  Infact there are no other AllowOverride options in the vhosts file other than the one I have just added.

Comment: Did some more digging and when I remove the following:

    <Location />
    order allow,deny
    deny from env=bad_bot
    allow from all
    </Location>
My .htaccess files start working again.  I did try moving this into Directory / rather than Location / however rather than getting forbidden user gets Apache Test Page and the blocking stops working.  But progress is progress!  Anyone able to advise a better way of structuring this part of my configuration?

Comment: I resolved this my moving the bad bot block into the vhost file of each domain and now use the vhost file to limit access.  A bit of a pain not being to be able to do it globally for the bots so if anyone else has a better answer would be welcome :) (Can't answer my own question yet)

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me often, and it's always because I'm not using the IP address that I think I'm using.  It sounds silly, but it's surprisingly easy to do, as most computers on the Internet can be represented by at least two IP addresses: one private for LAN, and one exposed to the Internet, typically through a router with NAT enabled.

For example, I was setting up a country IP block whitelist.  I figure that since I am in the same LAN as my server, I won't start off on the whitelist, which will make for a good testing opportunity.  However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to deny myself with a proper whitelist.  I had forgotten that I was accessing my server via its external IP: I was going to `home.example.com`, which I had mapped to my router's Internet IP address.  My router understood that I intended to loop back into the network, so it was seamless--until my IP address mattered.

There were hackish ways that I could get around the problem without going to the LAN IP, of course.  It might seem like Apache were buggy, since I could take out a single `Allow from` statement, and it would work.

The point is: if it doesn't work, check your IP address in the eyes of Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is in which order you define Deny/Allow or Allow/Deny? The file below worked for me as expected.

Your `.htaccess` file should look like:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 12.99.60.128
Allow from 79.18.77.63
Allow from 181.67.136.49
Deny from All
```

Don't forget: Thumbs up if it works for you too.